# Usar método delete com express

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express.js

Olá, estou tentando enviar um valor de um formulário (id) que vai ser tratado pelo express (não conheço bem os termos técnicos pra isso, se puderem me ajudar também), já procurei bastante mas não consigo passar o parâmetro id na action e nem acessar a função app.delete(). Como faço pra passar isso pro meu app.delete?

Meu form:

```
 <form  action=<"/produtos">  method="DELETE">
     <input id="id" type="text" name="id"/>
     <input type="submit"  value="REMOVER"/>
 </form>
```

Meu app.delete (estava fazendo curso da Alura):

```
app.delete('/produtos:id', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.params.id);
    var connection = app.infra.connectionFactory();
    var ProdutosDAO = new app.infra.ProdutosDAO(connection);
    var produtoID = req.params.id;
    console.log(produtoID);
    ProdutosDAO.remove(produtoID, function(erros, resultados){
      if(erros) res.send(erros.message);
      res.send("Produto " + produtoID + " removido");
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

Repara que tens um erro de sintaxe no HTML, `<` e `>` a mais. Deve ser `<form  action="/produtos" method="DELETE">`

Para facilitar usa-se um middleware para receberes esses parametros no `.body` do request. Um dos mais habituais (antigamente parte do Expree.js) é o `body-parser`. Se ainda não tens isso coloca no index da aplicação, logo depois de `const app = express();` assim:

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
```

---

Depois para receber no express parâmetros passados pela form podes usar o `req.body.id` assim:

```
app.delete('/produtos', function(req, res){
    console.log(req.body.id);
    // etc...
});
```

Comment: Ainda não funcionou. Um amigo disse que os forms não tem suporte aos métodos _PUT_ E _DELETE_ do _HTTP_. Pensei em usar uma rota tipo `/produtos/deletar/:id`, mas não sei como passar esse id na rota.

Comment: @IcaroRegoFernandes tens razão, forms só permitem `PUT` e `GET`. Se fizeres  `GET` podes usar `req.query.nomeDoParametro`, se usares `POST` podes usar `req.body.nomeDoParametro` se quiseres usar por url `/produtos/deletar/:id` podes usar `req.params.id`.